# Zend 3 - return function or access to var in view MVC

Tags: php, zend-framework3

Which method is correctly to show data in view?
Protected var in model and functions which returns parameter

```
$album->getAlbumTitle();
```

or public var in model with private tableGateway

```
$album->album_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are working, so both are correct maybe?

I would say it's not a ZF/PHP question, but more of an OOP question. Please read about Data Mapper VS Active record, and then encapsulation to make up your mind.

My own opinion would rather be using the first one, as you have some layer of encapsulation, therefore letting you add some logic if needed, or easily change your database schema without breaking all of your app.